# fluid simulation with blender and export to unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I simulated pouring water with blender and I want use it 
as animation in unity .
what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

this is not possible to do, at least not in the way your thinking, a fluid simulation for render use cannot just be exported and work in a game engine, unity wouldn't support such a thing, nothing does, also this isn't really on topic for here